# Can not press "run" in Intellij idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have updated my Java recently and since then i can not press "run" (the green arrow) anymore.
I tried to reinstall Intellij but it did not work.

Comment: Which version of java have you installed `javac -version` in terminal? Did you get any error/comment in IDE output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try right-clicking within the file that contains a `main` method, and click "Run CLASSNAME.main()". That should generate a run configuration for the file that will let you use the green play button.

Comment: No prob! That was one of my biggest gripes with IntelliJ at first after switching from Eclipse, but I suppose I can deal with right-clicking!